# Angular btn-group Add class to button if string exists in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a few buttons which I need to toggle an active class in each so I can change it's color when it's selected.

This is what I have:

I have this array:

```
this.selected  = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

The I have these buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button (click)="checkIfInArr('one')">One</button>
    <button (click)="checkIfInArr('two')">Two</button>
    <button (click)="checkIfInArr('three')">Three</button>
</div>
```

And a function idea here...

```
checkIfInArr(name) {
    if (this.selected.includes(name)) {
        // Add .active class to button 
    } else {
        // Remove .active class from button
    }
}
```

This is as far as I've got.

Basically I need to toggle a class on each of the buttons.

How can I get this done either this way or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it done that way, obtain the button's `ElementRef` too from the `(click)` callback. Then in the function, add or remove the `.active` class as you need.

So your HTML will now create elementRef variables with # and pass them to the callback. So you can have this:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button #one (click)="checkIfInArr('one', one)">One</button>
    <button #two (click)="checkIfInArr('two', two)">Two</button>
    <button #three (click)="checkIfInArr('three', three)">Three</button>
</div>
```

Then the callback function will now toggle the `.active`  class on the provided elementRef. So you can have this:

```
checkIfInArr(name: string, ref: ElementRef) {
    if (this.selected.includes(name)) {
        // Add .active class to button 
        ref.nativeElement.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        // Remove .active class from button
        ref.nativeElement.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: The references are not defined ... <button #one (click)="checkIfInArr('one', one)">One</button> ... the second one

Comment: Is that the error Angular is throwing after you've done both changes?

Comment: Error is: Argument of type 'HTMLButtonElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ElementRef<any>'.
  Property 'nativeElement' is missing in type 'HTMLButtonElement' but required in type 'ElementRef<any>'

Comment: Okay great. Remove the `.nativeElement` on those statements then let's see if it'll work. So change `ref.nativeElement.classList.add('active')` to `ref.classList.add('active')`. Do same for the remove too (in the else block). Also change the parameter type of the `ref` argument from ElementRef to HTMLButtonElement. Then check let's see.

Comment: That won't work either... can't use ref.classList.add('active')

Comment: Okay what's the error message this time

Comment: Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'

Comment: Wow now this is surpising because I know the type is meant to be ElementRef and was right at first. Okay can you send a Google Meet link so you share your screen and we correct it.

Comment: I appreciate it but I can't share my screen. Thanks anyway...I'll find a way for fix it...thanks again